# HTML to XML function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I currently have a function in jQuery where It will generate the HTML input fields into XML tags, But there is an issue am having at the moment, I am outputting what I put into the input fields which is great but I keep getting Undefined coming up followed by what I had entered and I cant figure out what it is, something minor but am not too sure.

Below is the function doing all the good stuff, ill link a fiddle so it offers a better insight into whats happening.

```
                $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
                console.log('test');
                $("#form").children().find("input").each(function() {

                    if ($(this).attr("type") == "text") {

                        output += $(this).attr("data-value");
                        output += $(this).val();
                    } else if ($(this).prop("tagName") == "BR" || $(this).prop("tagName") == "FORM") {
                        output += "&#xD;";
                    } else if ($(this).attr("type") == "submit") {

                        console.log("ignored");
                    } else {
                        output += $(this).attr("data-value");
                    }



                });

                $("#output").append(output);
```

Its a minor issue but I just cant see what it is, advice or pointed in the right direction would be great.

Fiddle Link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeSa8/25/)

Comment: your jsfiddle is not working. It contains invalid html, and you forgot to extract the javascript, css and external resources into their proper places. This makes it hard to reproduce your issue. My best guess is that it has something todo with the `$(this).attr("data-value")`.

Comment: Hmm that should work http://jsfiddle.net/PeSa8/25/, Yeah you would be right for sure, I know thats the issue, But I cant pinpoint what exactly is wrong with  $(this).attr("data-value"), If i remove the data-Value it removes the undefined but some remain, I just need to get rid of that, and the html div object tag

Comment: unfortunately version 7 is not working either. You say "undefined coming up followed by what I had entered". I can't find what I entered in the output, just lots of undefined.

Comment: I updated the JS fiddle with librarys etc the output am currently getting is [object HTMLDivElement]undefinedasasundefinedaasundefinedasa  "asa" being what I entered into the fields, Effectively I just need to somehow get rid of [object HTMLDivElement] and undefined, just a tad stuck on how to do that